# How to factorize a long expression without long division?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have this: $3n^{3} + 16n^{2} + 23n + 10$. I need to decompose it in (n+1)(n+1)(3n + 10). Using long division I can do it, but I was wondering, in order to save space on a long proof I'm writing  (and since apparently I don't remember all my high school algebra), is there a way to do it without long division?

Comment: Unless you’re writing the proof for a class in which you’re required to show even the most elementary details, I’d simply write $3n^3+16n^2+23n+10=(n+1)^2(3n+10)$ without going through the details of the calculation.

Comment: Are you looking for a way to justify $3n^{3} + 16n^{2} + 23n + 10=(n+1)(n+1)(3n + 10)$ in your proof?

Comment: what does factorize mean? Is it the same as factor?

Comment: In my experience, if you *know* something is a factor, then finding the quotient by long division is quick and routine, but coming up with the factor can be extremely difficult. Thus I'm a little puzzled by your comment "Using long division I can do it".

Comment: Uh, synthetic is quick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling your polynomial $p(n)$, you know that since $-1$ is a zero of both $p$ and $p'$, it follows that $(n+1)^2$ is a factor of $p$. It's a little quicker to divide $p$ by $n^2+2n+1$ (using long division) to get $3n+10$ than it is to divide by $3n+10$ to get $n^2+2n+1$, so that would save a little space and time.

Answer (score 0):

The result of a long division by a monic linear polynomial is obtained (it is the same) as the result of applying [Ruffini-Horner's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner%27s_method). Ruffini-Horner can be summarized in a small table.